# Magento 2 Pattern Library -- Date & Time Selectors

Tags: magento2, jquery, datepicker, pattern-library

I would like to implement the "Horizontally Stacked Time Range Picker" from the Magento 2 Pattern Library into an admin form input

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/pattern-library/getting-user-input/date_time_selector/date_time_selector.html

Does anyone have any working examples of exactly how to do this? I scoured through the entire admin, but couldn't find any working examples of the date+time picker.

Answer (score 1):

The customer grid filter has a date range option for `created_at`. It can be found in `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml` and currently looks like the following.

```
<column name="created_at">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Since</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Now the difference between this and the date fields in forms like the add new customer form is the item named `filter` but this will only work of filters and not for forms.

Now there is a Range element class `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Range` but that is not under the `DataType` folder with all the other form element fields. I also cannot see it being used in the form element definition as of yet but I am sure that it is possible to extend the form definitions.xml. I just dont know yet how :(

I have just read on [Magento2 dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-library/ui-library-component.html) that extension providers can extend these definitions but not add their own which too me seems a bit odd, unless you can take the date field and create your own based from this I see this as a big limitation.